# Should I use triggers in SQL to insert records?

Tags: sql, triggers

I would like to know if there is another option I can take to avoid using triggers.

I want to insert records into a QUEUE table when a table has changed via (DELETE, INSERT or UPDATE) of a record.  The current way I am doing is by using triggers for the target tables.

What are some other options?

Comment: Depends how they're being inserted, is this directly on the database or some application?

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to avoid triggers, you could revoke direct permissions from the tables and process everything through stored procedures.  The procedure would perform the operation as well as the queue entry.